# Excluding a table from a transaction rollback

Tags: sql, transactions, rollback

We have a table and a set of procedures that are used for generating pk ids. The table holds the last id, and the procedures gets the id, increments it, updates the table, and then returns the newly incremented id.

This procedure could potentially be within a transaction. The problem is that if the we have a rollback, it could potentially rollback to an id that is before any id's that came into use during the transaction (say generated from a different user or thread). Then when the id is incremented again, it will cause duplicates.

Is there any way to exclude the id generating table from a parent transaction to prevent this from happening?

To add detail our current problem...

First, we have a system we are preparing to migrate a lot of data into. The system consists of a ms-sql (2008) database, and a textml database. The sql database houses data less than 3 days old, while the textml acts as an archive for anything older. The textml db also relies on the sql db to provide ids' for particular fields. These fields are Identity PK's currently, and are generated on insertion before publishing to the texml db. We do not want to wash all our migrated data through sql since the records will flood the current system, both in terms of traffic and data. But at the same time we have no way of generating these id's since they are auto-incremented values that sql server controls.

Secondly, we have a system requirement which needs us to be able to pull an old asset out of the texml database and insert it back into the sql database with the original id's. This is done for correction and editing purposes, and if we alter the id's it will break relations downstream on clients system which we have no control over. Of course all this is an issue because id columns are Identity columns.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Does it have built in auto-incrementing that you could use instead of trying to roll your own?

Comment: Joe is right - this is why most RDBMS's have built-in `Identity` type functions.

Comment: If you have logic which determines when a rollback happens you could set the table back to the original value with/within the same logic.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good solution - I wouldn't do it myself. But if you _'got to do what you got to do'_, you may want to use a Timestamp column (binary) instead and convert it to int some how. This value would not be repeated even if you rollback the parent transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> procedures gets the id, increments it,
>   updates the table, and then returns
>   the newly incremented id

This will cause deadlocks. procedure must increment and return in one single, atomic, step, eg. by using the OUTPUT clause in SQL Server:

```
update ids
set id = id + 1
output inserted.id
where name= @name;
```

You don't have to worry about concurrency. The fact that you generate ids this way implies that only one transaction can increment an id, because the update will lock the row exclusively. You cannot get duplicates. You do get complete serialization of all operations (ie. no performance and low throughput) but that is a different issue. And this why you should use built-in mechanisms for generating sequences and identities. These are specific to each platform: [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) in MySQL, [`SEQUENCE`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/rdb/0307-sequences-130053.pdf) in Oracle, [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) and [`SEQUENCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in SQL Server (sequence only in Denali) etc etc.

*Updated*
As I read your edit, the only reason why you want control of the generated identities is to be able to insert back archived records. This is already possible, simply use [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx):

> Allows explicit values to be inserted
>   into the identity column of a table

Turn it on when you insert back the old record, then turn it back off:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT recordstable ON;
INSERT INTO recordstable (id, ...) values (@oldid, ...);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT recordstable OFF;
```

As for why manually generated ids serialize all operations: any transaction that generates an id will exclusively lock the row in the ids table. No other transaction can read or write that row until the first transaction commits or rolls back. Therefore there can be only one transaction generating an id on a table at any moment, ie. serialization.

Comment: This is some good information, particularly considering our current procedure is not atomic. I am not sure I understand the serialization issues you mentioned. The problem with using the built in mechanisms is that they offer no control on when to generate an id outside of a row insertion. I upvoted the your answer, and would love to mark it as the answer, but I am not sure it really addresses the intial question, or offers a solution to the issue at hand. I have also expanded the question to add more details to the problem.

Comment: Turning off the Identity Insert only solves the second part of the problem. There is still the issues dealing with the migration and the need for migrated data to obtain valid id's without having to go through the system. It is too bad we are not using denali, since sequences would be ideal for this. MS workarounds look like this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx.

Comment: All that being said, your info lead to a solid workaround, so thanks!